# The most important aspects when transitioning from React Native to Flutter

Tags: typescript, react-native, flutter, redux

Before starting a project, I always want to figure out the best ways to organize the project - the most important concepts are: How to structure `modules/components, ...` , and which suitable patterns should be use in

In React Native, the project structure, with Redux pattern, be often formed as:

```
 - /src
    - types
    - constants
    - components
        - collection
        - todolist
        - settings
        - etc ...
    - utils
    - reducers
    - store.ts
    - middleware.ts
    - rootReducer.ts
```

But when transitioning from React Native to Flutter, the concepts of project structure/pattern is so different.

It seem that all our source files should be located under `/lib` .

So, currently I've been facing with project structure to organize my `modules/components/ ...`, and the best `UI pattern` should be used in.

Could you please give me some ideas as detailed as possible?

Comment: Questions that are seeking a list of ideas are too broad for Stack Overflow, and are probably primarily a matter of opinion. The best questions here are single, specific questions that have a small number of potentially right answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the important factors to grow your self for learning flutter from the React Native background via [Official Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/react-native-devs)

> Just go through it and you're all set to rock the flutter floor.

Answer (score 2):

There is not best approach for flutter but i will give my own approach i like to have two files to separate the logic from the UI (core and models) in core i keep all the logic from HTTP request to dealing with  different logic and in the ui i keep all my views an shared styles and widgets

```
- core
    - models
    - viewmodels
    - services
- ui
    - shared
    - views
    - widgest
- main.dart
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just replicate your usual structure under lib/ rather than src/

When I do the first project on a new platform, I assume that half way through, I am going to suddenly ‘understand’ how we/I should have done it.

So just get stuck in with your usual methods and then let yourself stop and do a major refactor at the half-way stage.